# Не копируется содержимое в Adobe XD!

Tags: adobexd

Не копируется текст с Adobe XD. При вёрстки сайта с макета XD (программы Adobe XD), мне нужно скопировать код цвета. Например текст: "ILON LOREN" (в свойствах программы его color: #2b2a2c). Я выделяю его, копирую, перехожу в редактор кода, вставляю = ничего не происходит.

**Как выяснилось** оно вроде как копирует его в буфер, потому что **в самой программе** оно **вставляет**, но как только пробую вставить **в другом месте**, за пределами этой программы (*даже в текстовом документе или word*), то не получается.

**ЧТО ПРОБОВАЛ**
- Пробовал изменит ctrl+c/v на "копировать" и "вставить".
- Пробовал перезапускать программы и сам пк. 
- Пробовал искать решение в интернете.
- Пробовал найти в программе Adobe XD такое место, откуда оно всё же копировалось бы.

**Чего получилось добиться**
Нашёл инфу что может быть из-за вирусов, сканирую пк. Так же из-за неправильного и не полного деинсталляции программ.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопроса не совпадает с тематикой сайта Stack Overflow на русском

Comment: попробуйте обратится в поддержку adobe